# How can we put information buttons on the model using three js?

Tags: three.js

In the three js examples, I saw the Lamborghini website and there are information buttons placed on the car. How can we put these buttons? I've seen posts about it not being possible to put a clipPath that will interactively overlay the model in the model-viewer. I want to do a study on this subject, how can I do it?

[The area I see as an example on the Lamborghini website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq3gj.png)

How can we do this to a model that is not comprehensive as seen in the picture? For example a cube

Opening and closing information boxes when pressing buttons on the model

Comment: You could render them as billboards or sprites, and trace a ray from the cursor to detect a click or hover event. Alternatively, you could render them as HTML elements on top of your canvas, but then you need to transform them manually.